# Free software to use as aircraft register with photos

Tags: linux, database, photography, spreadsheet, database-browser

I'm sure there's a name for software of this kind, but Google hasn't been particularly helpful.

I'm looking for **online, self-hosted** software that will generate a database/spreadsheet table with columns of my own design. I want to make a searchable table of aircraft registrations and details of the aircraft and owners. If I need to design the DB tables beforehand and the software simply connects to it, that's also fine.

It would be great if I could link pictures to each record, perhaps after a user clicks on an aircraft in the list, the most recent pictures could be shown.

I'm looking for something more user-friendly than phpMyAdmin or other similar DB frontends, that can support multiple users, ideally on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

If you want more control and flexibility than possible in an online spreadsheet such as [Google Sheets](https://www.google.com/sheets/about/), you'll need to dabble in database app development.

## 4D & FileMaker

These two products are combo app development platform plus  database serve that help you define a table (or multiple tables in 4D, as it is a relational database), and then allow either a client app or web browser to connect to enter data and view data:

- [4D](http://www.4D.com/)
- [FileMaker](http://www.FileMaker.com/)

If you have a single list of records, use FileMaker. If you have multiple related tables (lists), use 4D. Both know how to store pictures.

Sounds like you have at least two tables: aircraft and photos, where each photo belongs to a particular airplane.

## Separate programming language and database

You can try software development using a programming language  separated from the database engine. Much more complicated than FileMaker/4D but you get any even more control.

For example, use the [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/) framework to write a server-side web app in pure Java that is automatically rendered in web-standards technology in a web browser without you having to learn HTTP, HTML, CSS, DOM, JavaScript, WebSockets, etc. See [this demo example](https://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/data-presentation/image) of presenting images/pictures, and press the "i" button for links to documentation.

Store the data in a database such as [H2](http://www.H2Database.com/) or [Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/) connected via [JDBC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jdbc).

Another possible toolset is [Xojo](http://www.Xojo.com/).